# C# 2.0 function which will return the formatted string

Tags: c#

I am using C# 2.0 and I have got below type of strings:

```
string id = "tcm:481-191820"; or "tcm:481-191820-32"; or "tcm:481-191820-8"; or "tcm:481-191820-128";
```

The last part of string doesn't matter i.e. (-32,-8,-128), whatever the string is it will render below result.

Now, I need to write one function which will take above string as input. something like below and will output as "**tcm:0-481-1**"

```
public static string GetPublicationID(string id)
{
   //this function will return as below output
   return "tcm:0-481-1"
}
```

Please suggest!!

Comment: This function should return substring of id?

Comment: @mau: with a bit of extra stuff in the middle (the "0-"). But yes, substring does seem to be the obvious solution.

Comment: Then it seems that Chris's solution is suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If final "-1" is static you could use:

```
public static string GetPublicationID(string id)
{
    int a = 1 + id.IndexOf(':');
    string first = id.Substring(0, a);
    string second = id.Substring(a, id.IndexOf('-') - a);
    return String.Format("{0}0-{1}-1", first, second);
}
```

or if "-1" is first part of next token, try this

```
public static string GetPublicationID(string id)
{
    int a = 1 + id.IndexOf(':');
    string first = id.Substring(0, a);
    string second = id.Substring(a, id.IndexOf('-') - a + 2);
    return String.Format("{0}0-{1}", first, second);
}
```

This syntax works even for different length patterns, assuming that your string is

```
first_part:second_part-anything_else
```

Comment: Hmmm... I hadn't considered that the -1 on the end might be static. I just assumed it was the first digit of the next block of numbers.

Comment: @Chris: honestly I don't know. Anyway my edited code should cover both situations ;)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
string.Format("{0}0-{1}", id.Substring(0,4), id.Substring(4,5));
```

This just uses substring to get the first four characters and then the next five and put them into the format with the 0- in there.

This does assume that your format is a fixed number of characters in each position (which it is in your example). If the string might be `abcd:4812...` then you will have to modify it slightly to pick up the right length of strings. See Marco's answer for that technique. I'd advise using his if you need the variable length and mine if the lengths stay the same.

Also as an additional note your original function of returning a static string does work for all of those examples you provided. I have assumed there are other numbers visible but if it is only the suffix that changes then you could happily use a static string (at which point declaring a constant or something rather than using a method would probably work better).

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory Regular Expression Answer:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string GetPublicationID(string id)
{
    Match m = RegEx.Match(@"tcm:([\d]+-[\d]{1})", id);
    if(m.Success)
        return string.Format("tcm:0-{0}", m.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value.ToString());
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Regex regxMatch = new Regex("(?<prefix>tcm:)(?<id>\\d+-\\d)(?<suffix>.)*",RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.Compiled);
    string regxReplace = "${prefix}0-${id}";

string GetPublicationID(string input) {
        return regxMatch.Replace(input, regxReplace);
}
    string test = "tcm:481-191820-128";
    stirng result = GetPublicationID(test);
    //result: tcm:0-481-1
```